# Connecting to guest vms on VMware ESXi

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I have an local server built in our office with  VMware ESXi 6.0.0 installed on it.  My local network is in the range 192.168.2.0/24 and the vmware host has the Ip address 192.168.2.254...

I have created a vm (centos)from vsphere client and set a private IP 192.168.2.240 to this VM and set the gatway to 192.168.2.1

I can access the vmware host node from my local computer (192.168.2.164) but cannot connect to the vm from any of our network. The vm ip 192.168.2.240 is pinging from the vmware host node..

I can access the console of the vm via vsphere and the ifconfig shows an additional network (virbro ) with another IP address 192.168.122.1

A lot knowledgebase says to enable bridge network from the vmware but I cannot see that option in my vmware...

Any Idea how can I get access to the vm and it can communicate to internet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a portgroup on the ESXi host which can access your 192.168.2.0/24 subnet. Then, update your VM to have a network adapter using that portgroup via the VM Settings.

I would recommend to start by reading through this: [Port Group Configuration for Virtual Machines](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-0BBDC715-2F93-4460-BF07-5778658C66D1.html)